# DISABLE WAMP starting automatically

Tags: windows, wamp

I recently installed WAMP, changed no settings, and now it is starting whenever I log in. Unlike most other questions I found on SE/Google, I would like it to only start when I run a file (`wampmanager.exe` or something else?). Is this possible, and how would I set it up (Windows 10, WAMP 3.06 64bit)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must have done something to make this happen. WAMPServer does not automatically start by default

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've got no idea what I changed, where might I change it back?

Comment: Question: Does wampmanager start automatically i.e. the icon in the system tray, or is it that APache and MYSQL start automatically?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Apache and MySQL, there is no icon unless I run `wampmanager`, which I have a shortcut for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have set the Apache and MYSQL services to autostart at boot.

To change these back do this :-

Run the services snapin

```
Windows Key + R
Enter services.msc
Press OK button
```

Look for the service name of either `wampapache` or `wampapache64`
Select that line
Right click on that line and select `Properties` in the menu

In the `Startup Type` dropdown select `Manual`

Do the same for the service called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` and set that to `Manual` as well.

Now after you boot, these 2 services should not start until you launch wampmanager.exe

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this soon (when I can access the machine in question)

Comment: They were already on manual, and trying to access localhost `refused to connect`. Seems to be operating normally now, no idea what was happening before...

Comment: I found that I also had a service Apache2.4 that needed to be set to manual

Comment: @ykay That probably means you have another Apache installation. You might want to uninstall that.